# Calculating sum of line length for hundred vector layers

Tags: qgis, line, batch, length, summarizing

I usually calculate total line length by adding a `$length` field and going to summary statistics. How would I do this if I have many layers? Is there a faster way? I batch added the $length to all of them.

Given a table of contents [Layer 1, Layer 2, Layer... ...Layer 100], how do I end up with a table of the form [[Layer 1: Total Length 10123, Layer 2: 2349 ...]?

Comment: Sounds like a Python task...Would be Python a possible way to go for you?

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 8):

Use PyQGIS:

```py
#Create an empty table in memory and add fields
newtable = QgsVectorLayer("None", "Results", "memory")
provider = newtable.dataProvider()
provider.addAttributes([QgsField('Layername', QVariant.String),
        QgsField('Length', QVariant.Double)])
newtable.updateFields()

#For each table added to the map calculate length and 
#  add layername and length to the created table
for lyr in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
    f = QgsFeature()
    total_length = sum([r.geometry().length() for r in lyr.getFeatures()]) #Possible to round decimals here
    f.setAttributes([lyr.name(), total_length])
    provider.addFeature(f)
    
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(newtable)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

> This solution is working (as long you not tired to repeat the pattern) but not as efficient as [one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/409007/99589) suggested by @BERA

There is a possibility using a ["Virtual Layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers) through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...`

Let's assume there are polyline layers called `'lines_test'` and `'lines_test2'`.

[image: input]

With the following query, it is possible to *end up with a table of lengths for all polyline layers*.

```sql
SELECT "lines_test" AS Layer,
       COUNT(*) Features,
       round(SUM(ST_length(geometry)), 6) AS Sumlength
FROM "lines_test"
UNION
SELECT "lines_test2" AS Layer,
       COUNT(*) Features,
       round(SUM(ST_length(geometry)), 6) AS Sumlength
FROM "lines_test2"
```

The output attribute table will look like

[image: output]

The above query embrace the following pattern:

```sql
SELECT "layername1" AS Layer,
       COUNT(*) Features,
       round(SUM(ST_length(geometry)), 6) AS Sumlength
FROM "layername1"
UNION
SELECT "layername2" AS Layer,
       COUNT(*) Features,
       round(SUM(ST_length(geometry)), 6) AS Sumlength
FROM "layername2"
UNION
...
UNION
SELECT "layernameN" AS Layer,
       COUNT(*) Features,
       round(SUM(ST_length(geometry)), 6) AS Sumlength
FROM "layernameN"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can easily create the sum of the length of all lines of all layers using this expression based on the variable `@layer_ids` (=List of all map layer IDs from the current project). Be aware: `array_sum` is [available since QGIS 3.18](https://qgis.org/de/site/forusers/visualchangelog318/index.html#feature-support-for-min-max-majority-sum-mean-and-median-functions-on-numerical-arrays)):

```
array_sum (
    array_foreach (
        @layer_ids,
        aggregate( 
            @element, 
            'sum',
            $length
)))
```

If you have only line-layers in your project, this is enough. If you have other layers that should be ignored, you must exclude them. To consider only layers of the type `Line`, thus excluding point, polygon and raster layers, use this expression (tribute for the `array_filter`-part to [this solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/409037/88814)):

```
array_sum (
    array_foreach (
        array_filter (
            @layer_ids,
            layer_property( 
                @element, 
                'geometry_type'
            )='Line'
        ),
        aggregate( 
            @element, 
            'sum',
            $length)))
```

*Screenshot: summing up the length of all lines of **all layers** with the expression:*
[image]

*Screenshot: the expression in action, taking into consideration only line-layers, ignoring all others (like point, polygon or raster layers etc.):*

[image]