# QGIS expressions: remove several elements at once from an array

Tags: qgis, expression, array

**The problem**

Using QGIS expressions with QGIS 3.20, I have an array and I want to exclude a number of elements from this array. Let's say my array is `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`, but I want to get an array like `[1,2,3]`, removing `[4,5,6]` from the initial array.

**What I tried I**

There is a function `array_remove_all (array,value)`, but with this, you can just remove one element: `array_remove_all (array (1,2,3,4,5,6),6)` reults in: `[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]`. I would like, basically, "subtract" one array from another array, pseudocode:

`array_subtract (array(1,2,3,4,5,6), array(4,5,6))` -> `[1,2,3]`.

`array_slice` is not what I'm looking for as it is based on start- and end-position.

**What I tried II: a workaround**

A workaround is this, but the `if`-condition expects an `else`-value, here: 'x'. If I could avoid creating an element in the array in case the `if`-condition is false, the problem would be solved, But like this, I have to create an output like `'x'` - even an empty output like `''` creates an element in the array:

```
array_foreach (
    array (1,2,3,4,5,6),
    if (
        @element <=3,
        @element, 
        'x'))
```

returns: `[ 1,2,3,'x', 'x', 'x' ]`

Now, the `'x'` can be removed with:

```
array_remove_all( array (1,2,3,'x', 'x', 'x'), 'x')
```

finally returns: `[ 1, 2, 3 ]`

**What I tried II: another workaround**

Using a `case`-statement instead of the `if`-condition to avoid an `else`-value does not help, as it still produces `NULL`-elements in the array that I then have to remove:

```
array_foreach (
    array (1,2,3,4,5,6),
    case
    when @element <=3 then @element
    end)
```

returns: `[ 1, 2, 3, NULL, NULL, NULL ]`

**The Question**

Is there a better solution to this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`array_filter()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#array-filter) combined with `in` operator, like:

```
array_filter(array(1,2,3,4,5,6), @element not in (4,5,6))
```